# Google's Color Tool for Android Apps

Tags: android, css, android-layout, android-studio, color-picker

Following Google's approach on Material Design, I stumbled upon it's [Color Tool](https://material.io/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0).

On the material design's [Color Page](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#)/Video they talk about different Color choices and how they suit each other. But I am having two questions regarding this:
First, after I picked a primary color in the color Tool, can I see somewhere which colors are supposed to fit to my primary color?

Second, if I export these colors (Color Tool -> Export to Android; so it should be made for Android Studio..),
I get a stylesheet like this:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<resources>
  <color name="primaryColor">#ff9800</color>
  <color name="primaryLightColor">#ffc947</color>
  <color name="primaryDarkColor">#c66900</color>
  <color name="secondaryColor">#ffab00</color>
  <color name="secondaryLightColor">#ffdd4b</color>
  <color name="secondaryDarkColor">#c67c00</color>
  <color name="primaryTextColor">#000000</color>
  <color name="secondaryTextColor">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

But on this style, there is color-style for icons, nor for accent etc.
So it is incompatible/incomplete for Google's Material Layout, which they are trying to push. So is there any guide on how to determine the missing and suggested colors for a theme? 
And why do the Color Tool and Android Studio work together so poorly, if they should be made for each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inbuilt Android Studio's Theme Editor For Finding Out Missing Colours In Your Style.
As per material design, secondary colour is also known as Accent Colour. Just Rename your secondary colour to colorAccent and you may remove secondary colour extra shades.
You may keep this name as well but some views such as FloatingActionButton uses colorAccent Resource By Default.
When you open styles.xml file, there will be a notification above to edit those styles in theme editor.
Have A good luck while building apps.